# Menu created with MySQL only works within website not outside

Tags: php, mysql, menu

I hope somebody can help me, because i got an menu that is auto generated via my MySQL db.

Because i got the menu to work inside the website and with that i mean it works with "test.dk/about" but the a href is empty when it's going out of the website like "http://google.com"...

btw it's just a very simple UL LI menu no dropdown or something.

Here is my script

```
    static function build_menu()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
    $menu = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row["is_external"]) {
            $url = $row["url"];
        } else if (empty($row["is_external"])) {
            $url = get_page_url($row["page_id"]);
        }
        $menu[] = array("name" => $row["name"], "page_id" => $row["page_id"], "is_external" => $row["url"], "url" => $url);
    }
    return $menu;
}

static function get_page_url($page_id)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT view_id FROM page WHERE id = '$page_id'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $view_id = $result["view_id"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT listen_path FROM view WHERE id = '$view_id'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $listen_path = $result["listen_path"];
    return $listen_path;
}

static function render()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu"); ?>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul><?php while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo self::get_page_url($item["page_id"]) ?>"><?php echo $item["name"] ?></a>
            </li>                <?php } ?></ul></div><?php
}
```

How can i fix it, so it works both internal and external?

```
<div class="menu"> <ul> <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li> <li><a href="/about">About</a></li> <li><a href="/Develop">Develop</a></li> <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
```

This should be `<li><a href="http://our.umbraco.org/">Support</a></li>; </ul> </div>`

Comment: view source, and show is the menu

Comment: <div class="menu">
        <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Develop">Develop</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Support</a></li> //This should be <li><a href="http://our.umbraco.org/">Support</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>

Comment: I assume that `self::get_page_url` is a method of the framework(?) you are using to get the URL for _internal_ pages only – so you would have to check _before_ calling that method, whether `$item["page_id"]` is an external URL or not – and only call the method if it is.

Comment: But in my DB, the external url also has an page_id, so i thought it would work, but i guess not.

Oh it was <a href="http://our.umbraco.org/"></a>

Comment: @Dagon: That is perfectly _valid_ HTML – it just doesn’t make much sense regarding where it is supposed to link to. (And anyway, it seems that it is only displayed here this way because of SO’s automatic linking mechanism, and is really `<a href="http://our.umbraco.org/">`)

Comment: fair call, valid=broke, and yeah its was S.O not O.P issue

Comment: Yeah it was me that was too fast, it was the 
<a href="http://our.umbraco.org/">, that i wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work after a while!

I simply just created an If else statement in the render function

```
static function render(){
    $menu_items = self::get();
    ?><div class="menu"><ul><?php while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu_items)) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php

                if(empty($item["is_external"]))
                {
                    echo self::get_page_url($item["page_id"]);
                }

                else if($item["is_external"] = 1)
                {
                    echo $item["url"];
                }

                 ?>"><?php echo $item["name"] ?></a>
            </li>                <?php } ?></ul></div><?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only check for an external link in the function build_menu(), but this function isn't called anywhere from your render() function.

The render() function only calls get_page_url() which doesn't distinguish between internal and external links.

Comment: So how do you want to use build_menu() in the render function?

Comment: That I don't get too. Why have you pasted the function `build_menu` which is not used at all?

Comment: I just don't know how to get it worked i tried so many things with it that i can't remember them, and then i tried the get_page_url directly

Answer (score 0):

Href parameter of external URL must start with **protocol declaration**, so with "http://" in your case.

So change your code in condition inside the function "build_menu", if the URL is external, add "http://" to it, something like this:

`$url = 'http://'.$row["url"];`

Comment: In the DB it has http:// so that should be correct when it get's print'ed or echo'ed :)

Comment: Oh, I see, it was hidden by SO.

Comment: So what's the problem? It doesn't display extrenal links at all?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't display any external links it just make the a href tag null :/

Comment: I think that you have probably mess in the data.

Comment: The database works fine because when i just echo all data out from the menu table in the database it display the url just fine, so it must be within my script :/

Comment: I mean wrong relations between the tables menu, page and view.

Comment: Try execute this in the SQL client: 
`SELECT * FROM menu AS m LEFT JOIN page AS p ON p.id = m.page_id LEFT JOIN view AS v ON v.id = p.view_id`. You should get all menu items with their URLs. Do you get the right data with external page URLs.

Comment: Yeah i get all four where there are three which don't have any url but these have listen_path and file_path instead

Comment: But you don't use URL at all. You use `listed_path` only in your `get_page_url` function. Sorry but it seems that you don't have a clue what you are doing.

Comment: URL in the `menu` table is filled for external menu entries only, right? `listed_path` is internal, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, but you don't use the "url" anywhere in your code. You use listen_path" only. So that's obvious there is no "url" for external menu entries, when you don't use the "url" anywhere. How did you expected, it could work? And it would be nice, if you'll describe, how did you solve that. For others.

Comment: Dawid, if you look i have answered the question with my PHP code and it tell's pretty much how i got it to work :)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't notice that before. Yep, that code does make a sense, finally. But it's really mess and ugly. You should learn a lot. Code has to be beautiful, it's not enough that it works somehow :)

Comment: This is my first time developing PHP, normally i'm a .NET C# developer... :P

Comment: This is not about language. It's about algorithmic thinking. If you understand programming it doesn't matter what language you use, algorithms are still the same (unless you use for example functional language). C and PHP are moreover very similar languages. Your problem wasn't related to PHP at all, it was related to the messy algorithm - you had function which was never called, you missed a variable in the output which you never used etc.